# Why wont my code run after i've dowloaded and imported pandas, numpy and matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, thonny

Relatively new to coding and having an issue with a project im working on. The project streams data from an embedded system to thonny via usb and stores the data in a csv. Im trying to graph the data etc using matplotlib, pandas, numpy etc but found out i didn't have them installed. I installed them using the built in package manager on thonny. But when i go to run the program the error "Process ended with exit code 3." keep coming up. If i take the graphing aspect and all related imports out the code runs fine adding to the csv just no graphing. The code isn't perfect as it is anyway, but i can't really continue without fixing this issue. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Code is below:

```
import serial
import csv
from time import time as current_time
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.port = "COM5"
db_list = []
print("Type CTRL + C to exit. (may take 5 seconds)")


ser.open()

start_time = current_time()

for i in range(10):
          
    microbitdata = str(ser.readline())
    
    decibel_level = microbitdata[2:]
    
    decibel_level = decibel_level.replace(" ","")#removes any spaces from the data
    
    decibel_level = decibel_level.replace("'","")#removes an opostrophies 
    
  
    decibel_level = decibel_level.replace("\\r\\n","")# replace \\r\\n with a blank space 
    
    decibel_level = decibel_level.replace("\\r","") #replace \\r with nothing
    
    decibel_level = decibel_level.replace("\\n","") #replace \\n with nothing 
    

    sleep(0.1)#break between data being added
    
    elapsed_time = round(current_time() - start_time)
    print("Elapsed time:", elapsed_time,"/db level:", decibel_level)
    sleep(1)  # Pauses the loop for 1 second
    decibel_level = int(decibel_level)
    db_list.append(decibel_level)
    
    safe = decibel_level <= 70
    potential_damage = 71<= decibel_level <= 90
    risk_of_hearing_loss = 91<= decibel_level <=119
    immediate_harm = decibel_level >= 120
        
    
    
    path = "Sound_level_data.csv"  #naming the file name 
    f = open(path, "a", newline='')#appends at the end of each line 

    writer = csv.writer(f)

    writer.writerow([elapsed_time,decibel_level])


    f.close()

#calc the trendline and plots the graph
csv = pd.read_csv('Sound_level_data.csv')
data = csv[['Time', 'Sound Level']]
x = data['elapsed_time']
y = data['decibel_level']



plt.scatter(x, y)

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")
plt.xlabel('db Level')
plt.ylabel('Time')

print("The slope is", z[0])
print("The intercept is", z[1])
print("The equation of the line is y="+str(round(z[0],2))+"x+"+str(round(z[1],2)))

plt.savefig("graph.png")
plt.show()
```

Tried reinstalling the imports but none will install to the latest stable version

Comment: `import matplotlib as plt` is very wrong. It should be `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.  Could you make a very small program that just imports matplotlib and plots one point? Do you only get that one short error message without context?  Anyway, try creating a very simple, short program. If that runs, try adding a bit more code.

Comment: Pls post the full error you are getting

Comment: @gtomer the entire error code is "Process ended with exit code 3." Nothing else comes up

Comment: @JohanC I changed that now, prgram is still not working, when i individually take out any of the three, either pandas, numpy or matplotlib.pyplot and try import them on their own  they all come back with "Process ended with exit code 3."

Comment: @JohanC I don't really understand what you mean by "headless mode"? Even just trying to import matplotlib.plt and not coding anything still brings up the error

Comment: "headless mode" means running matplotlib without showing anything on screen. The output would just be saved to file. So it would work on devices with limited capabilities (or servers).  Your question isn't really answerable, as we lack information about your exact environment and installation.

Comment: If you are working with Thonny, you might want to check [this blog post](https://www.technicallyproduct.co.uk/ide/modulenotfounderror-in-thonny-what-it-is-and-how-to-fix-it/)